# Should Christians come out strongly against groups that do evil in Christ's name?

Tags: good-and-evil

I finally found a safe way to ask this question.  There is a Christian army called the [Lords Army](http://www.christianitytoday.com/ct/2006/january/18.30.html), that is doing evil in Africa, after twisting Christian teachings, yet this group is supported by some Americans, such as  [Rush Limbaugh](http://mediamatters.org/blog/201110140018), and for those that want to read the [transcript](http://www.rushlimbaugh.com/daily/2011/10/14/obama_invades_uganda_targets_christians?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter).

So, when a group is demonstrating very anti-Christian teachings while purporting to be Christian, I realize we can pray for them.  These people are evil, so how strongly should Christians not only try to stop these people, but then are we beholden to go into these regions to serve the people and try to show Christ's teachings, such as when he washed the feet of his apostles?

Other examples of people doing evil in Jesus' name would be subjective, but this group I hope is not.

Comment: Let me explain why I suggest this is "not constructive". It is _not_ because I don't agree that the LRA is evil. In fact I think that's a pretty safe agreed on example that could be referenced. The problem is **I don't see what's being asked**. Obviously you're not asking for a judgement on whether the LRA is evil or not. It seems unlikely that you are asking "_Should Christians oppose evil?_" That leaves the bit about "_Should we oppose it strongly?_". Given no definition of "strongly" it sounds like you're asking for a brainstorming session on what opposition measures should be taken.

Comment: While the example of evil you have chosen may be agreeably non-subjective, what measures should be taken against evil in general and how "strongly" to react to things is subjective and there is no framework here for judging what a right or wrong answer to this question would be. The QnA format of SE sites is much better suited to asking about established current or historical doctrines rather than hashing out what Christians _should_ do and forging a new course of action. The latter should certainly be done by Christians, just maybe not by Christianity.SE.

Comment: See also: [What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/690)

Comment: If you have any feedback on this question (or this issue in general) feel free to comment here, bring it up in chat, or open a new meta post to discuss it!

Answer (score 1):

There may be better or more applicable teachings, but this reminds me of [Acts 4:32-5:11](http://www.usccb.org/bible/scripture.cfm?bk=Acts&ch=5) wherein the Christians were living and sharing their things yet a couple was hording for themselves.

Well, it didn't turn out too well for those folks, so if the LRA is as bad as [it's purported to be](http://www.catholicculture.org/news/headlines/index.cfm?storyid=10421&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20CatholicWorldNewsFeatureStories%20%28Catholic%20World%20News%20%28on%20CatholicCulture.org%29%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader), it won't turn out well for them etheir.  There's no basis for accepting acts of Christians who have [proven themselves anti-Christian](http://www.catholicculture.org/news/headlines/index.cfm?storyid=9177&utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20CatholicWorldNewsFeatureStories%20%28Catholic%20World%20News%20%28on%20CatholicCulture.org%29%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader).

But, is it up to our church leaders to denounce them?  I think so to some extent, and to some extent they do. But pastors are often more concerned with their flock than ones half a world away. It's really up to us all to bring about the Kingdom of Heaven on Earth as best we can.  Run for office, vote for good people, give money to good charities, raise good children, there's more you can do if your vocation allows for it, but that's all most of us can do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Christians should come out strongly (boldly) against groups that do evil in Christ's name..

First, thank you for bringing this to my attention. 
Second, there is provision for speaking boldly to rebuke, exhort, and convince. Not only to speak, but to do so boldly. To preach the Word!

**2 Timothy 3:13-17, 4:1-2**

But evil men and impostors will grow worse and worse, deceiving and being deceived. 14) But you must continue in the things which you have learned and been assured of, knowing from whom you have learned them, 15) and that from childhood you have known the Holy Scriptures, which are able to make you wise for salvation through faith which is in Christ Jesus. 16) All Scripture is given by inspiration of God, and is profitable for doctrine, for reproof, for correction, for instruction in righteousness, 17) that the man of God may be complete, thoroughly equipped for every good work.

**4:1** I charge you therefore before God and the Lord Jesus Christ, who will judge the living and the dead at His appearing and His kingdom: 2) Preach the word! Be ready in season and out of season. Convince, rebuke, exhort, with all longsuffering and teaching.

**Ephesians 6:19-20**
And for me, that utterance may be given to me, that I may open my mouth boldly to make known the mystery of the gospel, 20) for which I am an ambassador in chains; that in it I may speak boldly, as I ought to speak.

It appears, from the article you’ve referenced and what I found doing follow-up research, that Joseph Koney is a false teacher. It seems that this is a case where we are to **speak boldly, to convince, rebuke, reproof and correct**.